# Ada: linked list example in Naiditch's book

Tags: linked-list, ada

In Chapter 11: Access Types of the book: `Rendez-vous with Ada by Naiditch (1995)`, Naiditch gives a rather complete example on how to create a linked list that contains information about a restaurant. I understand largely the data structure following the book's example. I can understand that any information that the user is entering in the linked list will only exist during the lifetime of a program. The author is not storing any information about the restaurant say as text files. So what's the use of the linked list example if all information entered by the user is not stored after the user exits the program?

Does it make sense to store user entered information say in a text file and then read them into a linked list so as to do further operations on them? But then doing operations such as adding or deleting entries will disturb the original text file from which the linked list was read from at the start.

Thank you.

PS: As you might have noted, I am trying to get a real-life example of a linked list and I am new to this data structure as well.

Comment: Textbook examples are intended to demonstrate concepts.  They're not supposed to be useful in real life.  The idea is that if you've studied the example and understand the data structure, you can use it if it's needed as a small part of some larger program later on.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-TOC.html), the 1995 example predates the addition of `Containers` to the predefined library of Ada 2005. The textbook example may guide your understanding of concrete implementations encountered a particular Ada library. See [*8.1 Organization of containers*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-8-1.html) for an overview.

Comment: You are welcome; based on your reading, don't hesitate to edit your question to narrow the focus.

Comment: I see also some length information here: [link](http://wiki.ada-dk.org/ada.containers.vectors) which can be worthy of reading.